# Is it possible to print to a local printer with CFFILE?

Tags: printing, coldfusion

I'm building an application in ColdFusion that lets the user choose a group of photos and will let them be printed automatically, however, I need to print the file and not the webpage holding the images. Is this possible with CFFILE? If not what is the best way to do this?

Comment: "Printed where?", he asked.

Comment: To a printer on the local machine

Comment: Suggested reading: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfprint.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, great solution but i need to print .jpgs instead of PDFs

Comment: @johnnyc0506 A PDF is just a blank page. Put the picture on the page!

Comment: It's probably not achievable at all.  To access local print commands you would have to write an active-x control of some sort.  Then you would have to persuade each user to disregard the warnings they receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dan's suggestion of an Active-X control (even if it's possible) will only work for MSIE 11 and earlier. Active-X will not work for MS Edge or any non-MS browser. It's not a global, future-proof solution.

The best solution will be to convert the images to a multi-page PDF file as TRose suggests. You will then present the file to the user to download or view in the browser. The user will have to manually print the PDF file.

Here's why: ColdFusion is a server-side applicaiton server. It crafts content that is viewable via a web browser. For security reasons, web browsers cannot automatically aceess a user's local computer(1) and therefore cannot connect to any printer connected to that computer.

(1) This is also why we can't upload files without user interaction.

Comment: Thank you for this, i believe that making all the images PDFs would be a good solution and will test it out to see the outcome.